# Index out of range al realizar un update

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Al ejecutar la sentencia:

```
ps.setString(i ,text[i].getText());
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

> java.sql.SQLException Parameter index out of range (1 > number of
>   parameters, which is 0);

Este es el codigo :

```
void Guardar (JTable table , String tablebd , String [] sentencia , String clave , JTextField[] text , int numero ){
   //Jtable table = el nombre de la tabla en el frame
   //table bd = nombre de la tabla en la bd
   // String [] Sentancia = Será el query , van los nombres de las columnas segruidos con un =?, , excepto el ultimo que no tendra ,
        // Ej : {"nombre=? , apellido=? , telefono=? , direccion=? , sexo=? , email=?"}
   //clave = id de la tabla ; IDinvitado , IDevento , etc
   // TextField [] = lista de los txtfiend que hay en el frame , deben ser nombrados en el orden correspondiente a su lugar en el String [] sentencia
   // Numero = Cantidad de columnas en la tabla , que debe ser la misma cantidad de TExtField
   try{
       Concectar cc = new Concectar();
        Connection cn = cc.conexion();
        int fila = table.getSelectedRow();
        String sql = "UPDATE "+ tablebd + " SET " + sentencia.toString() +" WHERE "+ clave + " = " +table.getValueAt(fila,0);

       String dao =  (String) table.getValueAt(fila, 0);
       PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);

       for (int i = 1 ; i < numero ; i++){
       ps.setString(i ,text[i].getText());  
       }
       ps.executeUpdate();
      // Llenar(new String[]{"IDinvitado","nombre","apellido","telefono","direccion","sexo","email"},"invitados",7,table);
      // Limpiar(new JTextField []{txtNombreInvitado ,txtApellidoInvitado , txtTelefonoInvitado ,txtDireccionInvitado,txtEmailInvitado},5);
      bttnAgregarInvitado.setEnabled(true);
      bttnEliminarInvitado.setEnabled(true);
      bttnEditarInvitado.setEnabled(true);
      bttnGuardarInvitado.setEnabled(false);

   }catch (Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error "+ e.getMessage());};

}
```

El error se produce cuando invoco al metodo Guardar con los siguientes parametros:

```
 Guardar(jTable1 , "eventos", new String[]{" nombre=? , ","fecha = ? ,"," ubicacion = ? ,"," tipo = ? "},"IDevento", new JTextField[]{txtNombre , txtFecha , txtUbicacion,txtTipo},4);
`
```

Comment: Los índices de los arreglos comienzan desde cero. Tu ciclo `for` lo inicias desde uno.

Comment: Sigue igual . for (int i = 0 ; i < numero ; i++){
           ps.setString(i ,text[i].getText());  
           }

Comment: E inclusive si hago esto : for (int i = 0 ; i < numero ; i++){
           ps.setString(i+1 ,text[i].getText());  
           }

Comment: ¿Verificaste lo que regresa `sentencia.toString()` y/o el valor de la variable `sql`?

Comment: sentencia.toString() me devuelve esto : [Ljava.lang.String;@4072c5fc

Comment: Así es, estas obteniendo la representación como cadena de una referencia de objeto. La cual no contiene la cantidad de posicionadores `?` esperados en `ps`. Hacer `toString()` a un arreglo de primitivos no es lo mismo que con un arreglo de objetos.

Comment: Entonces cual seria la solucion amigo ? estoy desorientado

Comment: La instrucción sql `String sql = "UPDATE "+ tablebd + " SET " + sentencia.toString() +" WHERE "+ clave + " = " +table.getValueAt(fila,0);` no se está creando bien. Si haces un `System.out.println(sql)` verás que en realidad no tienes una instrucción SQL válida. El mensaje de error indica que en la misma no hay ningún placeholder `?` y en consecuencia el código falla cuando tratas de hacer esto `ps.setString(i ,text[i].getText()); ` debes revisar cómo se construye la variable `sql` y optar por optimizar tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Para armar la sentencia SQL a partir del arreglo tienes varias opciones, pero como ya manejas las comas puedes hacer:

```
String sql = "UPDATE "+ tablebd + " SET ";
for( String str : sentencia )
  sql += str;
sql += " WHERE "+ clave + " = " +table.getValueAt(fila,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, tu error se encuentra en la siguiente instrucción : 
`String sql = "UPDATE "+ tablebd + " SET " + sentencia.toString() +" WHERE "+ clave + " = " +table.getValueAt(fila,0);`

Especificamente en `sentencia.toString()`, para poder obtener todas los parametros es mejor hacer esto :

```
    String array[] = {"Hola","Mundo"};
    String str = "";
    for(String name : array){
        str += name;
    }
```